# can I check what site window.history.back() will bring the user to?

Tags: javascript, browser-history

in one of my webpages I want to send the user back to the previous page after some computation, but only if the previous page was a page from my website.

So I am wondering if there is an easy way to check that?

Thank you for any input!

Comment: No - you can't query the browser history. It's a security thing.

Comment: You'd like Google to be able to look at your entire browsing history?

Comment: They probably do already...but I don't even want to go there rolfv1 had the answer I was looking for.

Comment: Barmar - what on earth makes you think google cannot do that if you come with chrome?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can however check how you arrived at the current page by using 2 methods:

`document.referrer`, but that only works if the user didn't block that, and gives you some limited info.
A more robust method might be to set some information about the previous page in either the URL, or in a `SESSION` variable.

Comment: Ok this makes sense. I will give URL hash tags a try. Thanks for the good information! :)

Comment: Referrer is passed if target="_blank" link is clicked while you can't do "back" in a new tab.

Answer (score 3):

No.

> For security reasons the History object doesn't allow the non-privileged code to access the URLs of other pages in the session history, but it does allow it to navigate the session history.

[Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.history)

Comment: I don't need to access the URLs history  just want to know if there is more history to go to, otherwise doesn't make sense to expose the `.back()` method