# How to check if previous page has a specific URL before moving back in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url, redirect, back

After a button is clicked in my app I use `window.history.back()` but I would like to write in some logic to check what that back history (previous page URL) is and see if it was I expect before executing that back function. If the previous page URL is not what I am expecting I want to redirect the user to my homepage.

Is there a good way to do this?

Comment: Sounds like: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20129542/can-i-check-what-site-window-history-back-will-bring-the-user-to

Comment: Thank you I did not find that in my search.