# A page accessible only I redirect a user to it, not accesible directly

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I want to create a page which only accessible when I redirect a user to it from a certain page and it's not accessible directly. Meaning, if a user enters its url manually, he should be redirected to an error page or something like that.

Is there an easy way to accomplish that? That is, check if a user has been redirected to it from a certain page. I can think of creating a flag in a session, but I figure there must be a more idiomatic way.

Comment: Do you need this page to have its own URL? You could just not create a route to the page you want to be inaccessible (ie: Don't add it to `router.ex`), and have it be created by the `render` function whenever needed.

Comment: @PedroCastilho, how?

Comment: @PedroCastilho, how?

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20129542/can-i-check-what-site-window-history-back-will-bring-the-user-to) is a link to a similar question about checking the previous page the user was just looking at. As mentioned in that thread, you don't get direct access to what previous page the user was on for security purposes. Compounding with this, using something like `document.referrer` only works if the user has it enabled, which can cause consistency issues.

So I think your best bet is do go with storing a session variable that indicates what page the user was just looking at, as you suggested in your question.

Best.